# Assessing stochastic dominance from samples? ...and is Kruskal-Wallis useful?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

According to [wikipedia and other scattered software documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) Kruskal Wallis tests assess "stochastic dominance". But the original paper doesn't mention "dominance". Nor does Dunn's much-cited 1964 paper. A stata function documentation mentions that it tests dominance "that is, the probability that a randomly drawn observation from one group will be greater than a randomly drawn observation from another." [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1501500117). Does that relate to the different formal types of stochastic dominance, e.g. from decision theory [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering)? Can someone help clarifying what approaches there are to assess stochastic dominance (properly-defined) and particulary how and why are they related to Kruskal Wallis type approaches. Ideally a modern reference to clarify. Many thanks for the pointers!